# "Will see" vs "We'll see"

Tags: phrase-request, collocations, colloquial-language

In Russian, there's a phrase meaning 'We will see in what something will end up'. Literally, that is the form of the Russian verb *see* put in 2Sg.

Is there any colloquial phrase which has the same function in English?

Is it possible to use "Will see" in that sense? Or "We'll see"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "we will see" but "will see" is a bit curt and could be a mis-hearing of "we'll see".

There is also an expression

> **time will tell**

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/time_will_tell) says of it

> PHRASE
>   The truth or correctness of something will only be established at some time in the future.
>   *As to who was telling the truth, only time will tell.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20will%20tell) says

> *idiom*
>   used to say that the results of a situation will be known only after a certain amount of time has passed
>   *"Will he be OK?" "I don't know. Only time will tell."*